# tabs in variable not working

Tags: shell-script, scripting, ksh, aix

I have this lines that I will insert in a mail called "header".

```
header="
-------------------------------------
Name\tAge\tGender\tAddress
-------------------------------------
"
```

Unfortunately, the `\t` does not work as I expected it to be. I even tried to put the `\t` between these two ``` `` ```.

Then I put this `$header` in the auto-email.

```
mailx -s "$subject" -r "$from" "$to" <<-eof
$header

$body

$footer
eof
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? doing `echo -e $header` works fine with me

Comment: just want to have proper alignments of columns using the tabs, i thought its just as easy as above but it doesnt work on mine

Comment: Updated my answer to include the `mailx` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `\n` to add newlines to your header:

header="-------------------------------------\nName\tAge\tGender\tAddress\n-------------------------------------\n"

Then use for instance `echo -e $header` to display:

```
echo -e $header
-------------------------------------
Name    Age Gender  Address
-------------------------------------
```

If `echo -e` does not work, use `printf` instead. If your output starts with dashes call `printf -- "$header"` to tell `printf` to interpret the complete variable as output instead of trying to parse them as arguments.

After more testing the original variable also works with printf:

```
header="
-------------------------------------
Name\tAge\tGender\tAddress
-------------------------------------
"

printf -- "$header"

-------------------------------------
Name    Age     Gender  Address
-------------------------------------
```

To use this in `mailx` you can use:

```
mailx -s "$subject" -r "$from" "$to" <<eof
$header
$body
$footer
eof
```

Comment: `echo -e` does not work on mine. it will just echo `-e` as well

Comment: Which OS/Distro are you using?

Comment: my OS is AIX, shell is ksh

Comment: Can you try `printf -- "-------------------------------------\nName\tAge\tGender\tAddress\n-------------------------------------\n"`

Comment: The reason is that `echo -e` is non-standard, while in `ksh` `printf` will also work, as it is standard, and `ksh` (`ksh93` on AIX) supports also ANSI strings. .

Comment: what worked on me is ` header=``-------------------------------------\nName\tAge\tGender\tAddress\n-------------------------------------``  `

Answer (score 2):

If you use ANSI strings:

```
header=$'
-------------------------------------
Name\tAge\tGender\tAddress
-------------------------------------
'
```

you have the correct translation of any ANSI escaped characters already in your variable. (Note: the newline characters could also be defined as `\n`, but it wouldn't add to legibility in your case, so I'd keep your original format as also depicted in this answer).

There's also the possibility to let other tools do the conversion at every place where it is used (while the string still contains the textual representation); examples for that are: Using `echo -e` (if your version of `echo` supports that option), or using the variable as *format string* in `printf` where escapes will also be interpreted, as in: `printf "$header"`.

Discussion: Using `printf` has the advantage to be POSIX standard. Using ANSI strings has the advantage that the conversion is consistently  present in the variable, and needs no further interpretation.

Since (as the updated question shows) the variable will be used in context of a program (`mailx`) that will not do interpretation of escaped characters the variable needs to already contain the appropriate formatting; so using the *ANSI Strings* (with `ksh93` on AIX) seems to be the appropriate solution. For a standard conforming solution you could also re-assign the variable using `printf`, e.g.: `header="..." ; header=$( printf "$header" )`

Comment: Janis, can you please explain printf vs ANSI a bit more? If I read `man printf` I find the following: *"The  format  operands  support  the  full  range   of   ANSI
     C/C99/XPG6  formatting  specifiers  as  well  as  additional
     specifiers"*

Comment: @Lambert; Sure, please just tell me what sort of explanation do you need? - Since you already quoted the `printf` manpage I suppose that part is clear. - The *ANSI Strings* is a `ksh` feature that is also available in other shells (like `bash` or `zsh`); what it does is simply an interpretation of (ANSI-) escaped characters (similar to what is done in the `printf` format string), but since it's done with the definition of the string you need just one interpretation, and on every place where you use the variable no further interpretation/conversion of escaped characters is necessary.

Comment: @\Janis, thanks, after reading it over and with your last comment it is more clear to me know. (strange behaviour, if I use @Janis, it is replaced with nothing)

Comment: @Lambert; I noticed that "@"-issue as well with some account names; the notification reached me nonetheless. - BTW: I now consistently use a semicolon instead of a comma after the account name, and that fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to use awk:

```
$ echo "Name Age Gender Address" | awk -F' ' '{ printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4 }'
```

produces:

```
Name    Age     Gender  Address
```

Or using printf directly:

```
$ printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n" Name Age Gender Address
```

produces:

```
Name    Age     Gender  Address
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man echo`

> Normally you could distinguish between a flag and a string that begins with a hyphen by using a  (double hyphen). Since no flags are supported with the echo command, a  (double hyphen) is treated literally.

And in the 2nd example:

> Note: You must put the message in quotation marks if it contains escape sequences. Otherwise, the shell interprets the \ (backslash) as a metacharacter and treats the \ differently.

And indeed, on AIX:

```
~> header="
-------------------------------------
Name\tAge\tGender\tAddress
-------------------------------------
"

~> echo -e $header
-e ------------------------------------- Name   Age     Gender  Address -------------------------------------
~> echo "$header"

-------------------------------------
Name    Age     Gender  Address
-------------------------------------
```